# What's the point of having a "link"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

When reviewing questions/answers on Stack Overflow, for example:
[image]
The site allows me to click on the question link. However, under the "viewed 22 times" text, there is another "link", which links to the same question:

[image]

My question is: What is the point of the less-obvious "link"? I'm pretty sure that everyone can see the big question link at the top.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that everyone can see the big question link at the top."
You'd like to think so, but people didn't, and kept asking for a link, so a "link" was added.

Comment: @Servy Who asked for another link?

Comment: Some guy in a green hat.

Comment: you will be thankful for the link if you come across an audit particularly a bad one.

Comment: @SurajRao What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @Don'tPanic ???

Comment: @Xcoder only that if you come across an audit, sometimes the only way to find the correct response is to go to the actual post...

Comment: @SurajRao Yes, but there is already a large link towards the top, which is my question...

Comment: @Xcoder ah, sorry, I was making a joke referencing [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(The_Legend_of_Zelda)).

Comment: @Don'tPanic Lol ok, I get it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That link goes to the post under review. And if you're reviewing an answer, there is no "big link at the top". :)

It doesn't harm anything (and helps with muscle memory) to just show the link at all times, though, regardless of the type of post you're looking at.

Comment: To be fair, when reviewing answers, there is a big link in the middle.

Comment: @TinyGiant Is there? I guess "share" is there below the answer, but it's not exactly big.

Comment: The sidebar link goes to the answer in that situation, not the question.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that usually the question that the answer is attached to is displayed (grayed out) below the answer, with the title of the question linkified.

Comment: @TinyGiant Ahh yeah, we do that. But that's not where the sidebar "link" on the answer under review goes. It points to the post under review.

Comment: That is definitely an important distinction.

Comment: @TinyGiant Good point, I updated my answer.

Comment: @AdamLear Good point with the answer review...

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, I suppose.